# How to display non-existing images the way IE/Opera does?

Tags: firefox

My Firefox 3.0.4 does not display non-existing images at all, or it displays the image alt as plain text (if available).
This way I would have no idea that there is supposed to be an image there.

Does anyone know if there is a way to make it work like IE/Opera? (ie. display a box even if the image file doesn't exists) - plugin or anything?

Test image: [image: [broken image test]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My extension, [FeatureFix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/featurefix/), now contains a comprehensive section in its configuration GUI ("advanced/developer tweaks") to configure broken/loading image placeholders.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I hope you would keep maintaining the add-on. Some people still prefer firefox. Or better could you release simple add-on just for showing broken image placeholder?

Answer (score 3):

There is a setting in about:config that is supposed to do just this: `browser.display.show_image_placeholders`. However, it doesn't do anything on its own.

You need to [add a rule to `userContent.css`](http://blog.doxmart.com/2009/08/11/a-quick-tip-on-enabling-broken-image-placeholders-in-firefox-3-and-beyond/) like this:

```
/*
 * Show image placeholders
 */
@-moz-document url-prefix(http), url-prefix(https), url-prefix(file) {
  img:-moz-broken {
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
  }
}
```

Then images will be displayed like this:

> [image: example screenshot]

Note that this hides the alt text, unlike Chrome which shows the alt text next to the placeholder.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the [Firebug Plugin](http://getfirebug.com/). It won't change how the images show up, but it does have a network tab that you can click to see which resources were gotten by firefox (and how fast). As well, it will tell you what images, js files and css files it was not able to get. It's incredibly handy for web development.

It also has a ton of other great features like JS debugging, and so much more.

Comment: In Firefox 4 or later, you can activate the built-in developer console (Ctrl+Shift+K), and see the missing requests. Still, this is nowhere near as usable as simply displaying a broken image placeholder..

Answer (score 1):

There's an experimental [Force Image Placeholders](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7811) plugin which attempts to do what you request.  I haven't used it, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately this link now goes to a page with the message: This add-on has been disabled by an administrator.

Comment: My extension, [FeatureFix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/featurefix/), now contains a comprehensive section in its configuration GUI ("advanced/developer tweaks") to configure broken/loading image placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another addon-based workaround.

- Get the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108) addon for Firefox, allowing you to apply your own styling information.
- Add a background to all `<img>` tags.  If the image loads, you won't see it.

But be warned that, if any images rely on transparency, the new default background will show through.

Comment: Merged information from this user's second answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of Pim Jager's suggestion, but it seems as though you'll need to force the image to display with something like "display: block;". This has the advantage of allowing you to specify additional styles via CSS that will show if the image doesn't - e.g. a background-color, or even a background-image. YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

As far as i know there is no plugin, Images should have a width and height specified like so:

```
<img src='...' width='100' height='100' alt='...'></img>
or
<img src='...' alt='...' style='width:100px; height:100px;'></img>
```

Then firefox will reserve the appropiate space for the images.

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to display a placeholder for broken images, as IE does (a blank image with a red 'X').

Answer (score -1):

Nothing works, based on experience and all research on tis matter, Firefox will not (in Windows anyway) display broken icon/image placeholders icon not matter what css and about:config settings.

Worst is all other browser do it by default, so if you want to know whats really going on dump Firefox.