# Force Firefox to render empty image within dimensions specified by CSS

Tags: html, css, image, alt

All major browsers except FF render images with invalid src attribute within it's dimensions as specified by CSS or by width / height attributes. Only FF will render the alt attribute as it were text node, ignoring dimensions, which breaks layout in many cases.

Is there a way to force FF to render image within specified dimensions?

Comment: Code? Example? Screenshot? Anything?

Comment: Not sure but have you tried adding `display:inline-block` to the image css? Perhaps when FF converts it to a text node it becomes functionally the same as a `span` and ignores `width` and `height` css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to write `width:` and `height` attribute in `img` tag itself or use `!important` for `width` and `height`  in CSS

Comment: Yes, thanks. Setting attributes didn't work, but adding !important to declaration in CSS made it work, along with overflow:hidden.

Comment: The !important declaration is one of the worst ideas ever created, I can't believe someone would suggest that. Fix the root issue with the proper methods instead, !important tag was created for inept developers exclusively.

Answer (score 11):

You should change the DOM element representation

```css
img{
 display:block;
}
```

or

```css
img{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

or

```css
img{
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try adding this rule to the css:

```
    @-moz-document url-prefix(http), url-prefix(file) {
  img:-moz-broken{
    -moz-force-broken-image-icon:1;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
}
```

[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/v5wqf/)

source from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6744791/1915183

Comment: I combined `:-moz-broken` with `display: inline-block`. Works for me!

Comment: Great suggestion, I always wanted back the icon for broken images, it makes it much easier to locate them quickly... thanks. Better remove the width and height from CSS and just use the self width and height attributes from each image.